# Lower Order Functional Programming, is it a good style in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am wondering if it is a good practice to apply functional programming style in Scala, even it is a simple switch case workflow.

For example:

Program 1:

```
def myMethod1():Unit = {

    ....
}

def myMethod2():Unit = {

    ...
}


def execFunc(myMethod: Unit=>Unit): Unit ={

    myMethod(...)

}

def main((args:Array[String]) {

    if(args(0) == "1")
    {
       execFunc(myMethod1)
    }
    else
    {
       execFunc(myMethod2) 
    }  

}
```

Program 2:

```
def myMethod1():Unit = {

    ....
}

def myMethod2():Unit = {

    ...
}


def execFunc(methodID:String): Unit ={

    if(methodID == "1")
    {
       myMethod1()
    }
    else
    {
       myMethod2()
    }

}

def main((args:Array[String]) {

   execFunc(args(0))

}
```

The Program 1 is passing a method directly as a parameter, and the program 2 is traditional way to handle switch task.

I would like to know, in Scala, which style is better, and why?

Comment: Why would you ever use the first way? I can't see any gains, unless you neglected to mention something important regarding the use case.

Comment: Why do you need a method that calls its parameter and does absolutely nothing else? Why did your second example move the if-statement from `main` to `execFunc`? I feel like you abstracted away your actual question.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, the first way is to apply functional programming style, isn't it suggested in Scala?

Comment: There is no important use in this case. I am simply asking which "style" is better in Scala. Try to pass function as parameter, or try to avoid this way. Don't think too much.

Comment: @lserlohn "Functional programming" is a broad topic, and every aspect of it has a time and place. Passing a function just for the sake of passing a function isn't helpful. Maybe what I should have asked is, what specifically are you trying to accomplish in the first way? In this example, it just looks like you're passing the function into another function just to execute the passed function in a different scope.

Comment: @lserlohn Passing a function is great when it's needed like to use `map`, but it isn't simply better across the board just because functional languages tend to have functions as first class objects. There needs to be a purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since functional languages tend to have functions as first class objects, and emphasize passing functions around to simplify code, the use of higher order functions could be considered more functional leaning.

*That said*, passing around functions just to pass around functions isn't useful. If you have a legitimate use case, sure! Make use of whatever tools you need if you think it will help you write better code. Make sure you're using the tools appropriately though.

The problem with your first bit of code is, at least in this example, you gain *nothing* by passing `method1` and `2` in. You're just calling the function in a different scope, and alone, I can't see that helping anything.

Where might you gain from using higher order functions? Say you have a few methods, and all the methods may throw the same exception, and they all need to have their exceptions handled in the same general way. What are your options?

- You could write out duplicate `try` blocks around each call to each method. That can get bloated fast though, and what happens when you need to change the functionality?
- You could write a higher order function that contains the common code, and pass the throwing function in; executing it within the try block (my Scala is very rusty):

  ```
  def handle(f: () => Int, throwDefault: Int): Int = {
      try {
          return f();
      } catch {
          case e: SomeException => {
              logOrWhatever(e);
              return throwDefault;
          }
      }
  }  

  println(handle(method1, 5))
  println(handle(method2, 10))
  ```